# Import keypair AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, boto3

I have successfully created Infra on AWS using boto3 where I created "MyKeyPair"

Now I am trying when I try to use the import keypair feature, under "ec2-> Network & Security", it is asking for the public part of the key to download.

I have the private part of the key printed on the terminal, where can I find the public key part

Regards

Surya

Answer (score 3):

The public key is part of the private key file.

Save your private key and name it "privkey.pem" or anything you want.

AWS wants the public key in SSH format. This command will extract the public key:

```
ssh-keygen -y -f privkey.pem > pubkey.pem
```

Now you can upload pubkey.pem using the console or the CLI.

```
aws ec2 import-key-pair --key-name "MyPubicKey" --public-key-material file://pubkey.pub --region 'us-west-2'
```

Of course modify the command line with your keyname, filename, region.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
ssh-keygen -m PEM -f key.pem

ssh-keygen -y -f key.pem > key.pem.pub

aws ec2 import-key-pair --key-name AwsKeyName \ 
     --public-key-material $(openssl enc -base64 -A -in key.pem.pub)
```